# Help with sum of two random variables proof

Tags: probability, random-variables

I can't explain why the following equality holds. Can someone help elaborate?

> Let $X$, $Y$ be two discrete random variables with a joint mass function.
>
> $\{ X + Y = z \} = \bigcup_x\limits (\{ X = x \} \cap \{ Y = z-x \})$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for an $x$

$$\{ X = x \} \text{ and } \{ Y = z-x \} $$

hold or in other words

$$\{ X = x \} \cap \{ Y = z-x \}, $$

holds then

$$\{X+Y=z\}$$

holds as well.

So, if there exists at least one $x$ for which the first two event occur then the third one occurs too. This is exactly what

$$\bigcup_x\limits (\{ X = x \} \cap \{ Y = z-x \}).$$

means. The latter formula expresses that either for "this" $x$ or for "that" $x$ or for "some" $x$ $\{ X = x \} \cap \{ Y = z-x \}$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

$X,Y$ are functions that map the sample space, let's call it $\Omega$, to real values.

The constraint $X+Y=z$ entails that for any outcome where $X=x$ then $Y=z-x$ also, which means that we may partition the sample space using the support of $X$.

$$\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)+Y(\omega)=z\} ~\equiv~\bigcup_{x\in X(\Omega)}\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x~\wedge~ Y(\omega)=z-x\}$$

The event where $X+Y=z$ is equal to the union of all events where $X=x$ and $Y=z-x$, for all values of $x$ in the support of $X$.

That is quite often abbreviated as:

$$\{X+Y=z\} ~\equiv~ {\bigcup}_x(\{X=x\}\cap\{Y=z-x\})$$